# Passing array range as argument to a function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arguments

is there a way to pass array-range as argument to function ?
Something like :

```
> blah(ary,arg1=1:5)

def blah(ary,arg1): print ary[arg1]
```

Comment: [`slice(1, 5)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python accepts the `1:5` syntax only within square brackets.  The interpreter converts it into a `slice` object.  The `__getitem__` method of the object then applies the slice.

Look at `numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` for some functions that take advantage of this.  Actually they aren't functions, but rather classes that define their own `__getitem__` methods.  That file may give you ideas.

But if you aren't up to that, then possibilities include:

```
blah(arr, slice(1, 5))
blah(arr, np.r_[1:5])
```

`nd_grid`, `mgrid`, `ogrid` extend the 'slice' concept to accept an imaginary 'step' value:

```
mgrid[-1:1:5j]
# array([-1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ])
```

Just be aware that anything which expands on a slice before passing it to your `blah` function, won't know about the shape of the other argument.  So `np.r_[:-1]` just returns `[]`.

And `None` can be used in `slice`: e.g. `slice(None,None,-1)` is equivalent of `[::-1]`.

Comment: How do I check if the argument I received is slice() vs ordinary number ? I got it isinstance(x,slice)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) function

```
>>> def blah(ary,arg1):
...     print ary[arg1]
>>> blah(range(10), slice(1, 5))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```
def blah(ary, arg):
    arg = map(int, arg.split(":"))
    print ary[arg[0]:arg[1]]

blah([1,2,3,4,5,6],"2:5")
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [saw it happen today](https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book-3rd-edition/blob/14b425c9b93cff9038f5bb48463b8e3d44072aa4/ch03/ch03.py#L208) and I thought it was curious, notice that they are passing the **argument test_idx** as a **plain range**

```
plot_decision_regions(X=X_combined_std, y=y_combined,
                      classifier=ppn, test_idx=range(105, 150))
```

## So what does this do in the end?

Using it to slice a *Numpy Array*

ndarray[range(105, 150), :]

However when I test this by copying the ndarray value, instantiate it and try to slice it myself (basically makes a list instead) it won't allow me to pass that range on the slice it seems.

> [[ 0.73088538  1.57698181], [ 0.17316034  0.1348488 ]]
>
> ## which I extracted/copied from an ndarray when you click to set new value
>
> > > erick = [[ 0.73088538  1.57698181], [ 0.17316034  0.1348488 ]]
>
> -- SyntaxError. invalid syntax
>
> ## had to put the commas to be accepted as a syntax and instantiates it as a list obj
>
> > > erick = [[ 0.73088538, 1.57698181], [ 0.17316034, 0.1348488 ]]
> > >
> > > erick[:]
>
> (works, returning whole thing)
>
> > > erick[range(0, 1), :]
>
> -- TypeError. list indices must be integrers or slices, not tuple
>
> (breaks, we tested that slicing works before so it has to do with the range)

[image]

## Try again with a homebrew Numpy Array (spoiler, it works)

```
erickNpa = np.asarray(erick, dtype=np.float32)
erickNpa[range(0, 1), :]
```

[image]

---

## Conclussion

You **can pass range as arguments** as seen on the *first part*, at some point the *code wasn't executing* but that had to do with the nature of what it was doing (using it to slice a list), however with the right scaffolding everything seems to work as proved when using a Numpy Array instead.

---

---

## Sample Code

I will also put the *function def* in case the git gets taken down even tho I linked the line.

```
def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, test_idx=None, resolution=0.02):

    # setup marker generator and color map
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^', 'v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])

    # plot the decision surface
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution),
                           np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha=0.3, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())

    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(x=X[y == cl, 0], 
                    y=X[y == cl, 1],
                    alpha=0.8, 
                    c=colors[idx],
                    marker=markers[idx], 
                    label=cl, 
                    edgecolor='black')

    # highlight test examples
    if test_idx:
        # plot all examples
        X_test, y_test = X[test_idx, :], y[test_idx]

        plt.scatter(X_test[:, 0],
                    X_test[:, 1],
                    c='',
                    edgecolor='black',
                    alpha=1.0,
                    linewidth=1,
                    marker='o',
                    s=100, 
                    label='test set')


# Training a perceptron model using the standardized training data:



X_combined_std = np.vstack((X_train_std, X_test_std))
y_combined = np.hstack((y_train, y_test))

plot_decision_regions(X=X_combined_std, y=y_combined,
                      classifier=ppn, test_idx=range(105, 150))
plt.xlabel('petal length [standardized]')
plt.ylabel('petal width [standardized]')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.tight_layout()
#plt.savefig('images/03_01.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```